# Can we make UIView height always resize with the height of UIStackView inside?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionviewcell, uistackview

I have a content view (this content view I will use as a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` content later) which has an `UIStackView` inside. Inside that stack view, I add some labels, view. And I calculate some conditions to make sure that when data of a label is empty, that label will be hidden and the stack view will auto change the height and vice versa, if they have data I'll show them and stack view update the height again.

Now I wanna know how can I make the content view height always follow the `UIStackView` height whenever it's changing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes,

here a magic line that refresh your cell when you change its content size (like when hidding ou showing a arranged subview in a UIStackview)

```
class MyCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

...

func showArrangedSubview() {
    // recompute resized cell
    self.myArrangeSubview.isHidden = false
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already made your UIStackView to have a dynamic height following its children, then all you need is to add constraints between UIStackView and your content view and it will resize automatically as well.

Now, if you add that content view inside a UICollectionViewCell, then you must make sure to call UICollectionView.reloadData() whenever you change the content of your UIStackView. That way the collection view will recalculate the size and render the cell again. You also have the option to reload a single cell in the collection view if you have a way to determine its indexPath.

Note: Take care of CollectionViewFlowLayout and what size it dictates to the cell. It's recommended that you tell the flow layout the estimated height of your cell via `layout.estimatedHeight`.